# Firebase cloud function admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I tried to split all my function in many files but I've a problem with firebase-admin initialization.
I've my first file like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const userHandler = require('./user')
```

and second file user.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
...
exports.update = (req, res) => {
   admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.body).catch(error => {console.log(error)}
}
```

All in a single file it works perfectly, in 2 separate file give me this error:

```
ReferenceError: ISTANCE_NAME is not defined
```

I can't do a second initializeApp in a user.js because firebase throw an error:

> Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called
>   initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the
>   second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp()
>   once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second
>   argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.

How I can use the same istance of admin shared in 2 files?
I've tried also to put the initializeApp function in another file and import it but not works, same error (ISTANCE_NAME is not defined)

Comment: did you figure this out eventually? If so, please share the answer.

Answer (score 1):

that's a good question.

So you're correct in saying that you can only call `admin.initializeApp()` once.

#### index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const userHandler = require('./user')
```

#### user.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
```

You do not need to initialize it again. The configuration is stored correctly after it's first initialized.

Alternatively, you can do messier things like a `getAdmin()` function.

The way I've done it in the past is have the functions defined and make separate files with **handler** functions, which look like

```
updateHandler(req, res, admin); // or the other
updateHander(whateverParamsToOtherFile);
```

### Note

All your functions must be exported from the `index.js` file to be correctly deployed on Firebase. I'd recommend the `index.js` to store all the functions and it calls handlers from other files.

Through parameter passing, you can achieve the result you're after. But in the specific case of `admin.initializeApp()`, it'll work fine in other files if it's initialized in the `index.js`.